# Eliminar propiedades dentro de un objeto en javascript si es null

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Estoy creando una API para anuncios, para optimizar el código quiero agregar filtros con los queries de las peticiones y no hacer varios endpoints. Actualmente me encuentro usando mongoose y con el método `find` devuelvo todos los anuncios, pero en la documentación encontré que este método puede recibir un objeto con parámetros para filtrar, entonces estoy tratando de crear este objeto basado en los queries, lo cual tengo todo de la siguiente manera:

```
    app.get('/items', (req, res) => {
    const active = req.query.active;
    const category = req.query.category;
    const skip = Number(req.query.skip) || 0;
    const limit = Number(req.query.limit) || 20;

    const filter = {
        category : (category) ? {category : category } :{category : '' }  ,
        state: (active) ? { state: active } : { state: true }
    }

    User.find(filter, 'title price img state created')
    Ads.find()
        .skip(skip)
        .limit(limit)
        .exec((err, adsDB) => {

            // if error
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    ok: false,
                    err
                })
            }

            User.countDocuments(filter, (err, count) => {
                // if success
                res.json({
                    ok: true,
                    pages: Math.ceil(count / limit),
                    total: (err) ? 'error' : count,
                    users: adsDB
                })
            })
        })
})
```

En el objeto `filter` estoy recuperando la data que existe con el operador ternario, pero me estoy dando cuenta, por ejemplo con 'category', que esta siempre tendrá un valor ya sea si la propiedad viene en el query con el request o no, y ya que todos tienen una categoría, este filtro siempre se aplicará. ¿Cómo remuevo esa propiedad para que no exista dentro del objeto si es null?

Mi duda es por ejemplo si lo siguiente no existe:

```
const category = req.query.category;
```

Que se remueva de mi objeto o que tenga una condición que no filtre la data.

Comment: Si el objeto es nulo significa que su contenido es invalido o esta discapacitado, porfavor contacte a la linea de emergencia al 777 para que lo revisen, jajaj bueno, mira fuera de bromas la pregunta creo que esta un poco confusa, es decir, yo por ahora lo que te entiendo es que quieres que el objeto no te llegue con una propiedad que en sus valores sea nula, es decir contenga un `null`, es esto a lo que te refieres?, tienes que ser un poco mas especifico, ya que hay varias maneras de interpretarlo.

Comment: Si ese es el caso tu dices que estas usando mongoose y mongodb por lo que deberias primero comprobar del lado de `nodeJS` si la data que le vas a enviar al frontend tiene contenido (si no son null), de lo contrario simplemente no le asignas esa propiedad al objeto, lo mejor para hacer esa asignacion es un filter que te mire por cada informacion que necesitas si esta es nula o no, si no es nula simplemente se establece la propiedad del objeto con su valor. de lo contrario se salta esa iteracion o simplemente se ignora la asignacion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea crear un filtro basado en las consultas (*queries*) realizadas en la petición `http`, de tal forma que el filtro refleje correctamente la consulta.

El filtro será usado en una consulta a una(s) colección(es) de una Base de Datos [MongoDB](https://mongodb.com), usando el popular ODM [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/).

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es simple, no necesitas *eliminar* la propiedad del objeto, lo que necesitas es crear el objeto de filtro usando los valores provenientes de la consulta.

Una forma muy sencilla, puede ser la siguiente:

```js
app.get('/items', (req, res) => {
  const active = req.query && req.query.active;
  const category = req.query && req.query.category;
  const skip = (req.query && Number(req.query.skip)) || 0;
  const limit = (req.query && Number(req.query.limit)) || 20;

  const filter = {}
  if(category) {
    filter.category = category;
  }
  if(active) {
    filter.active = active;
  }
  // ....
```

Lo primero que estamos haciendo en este caso es usar el [operador lógico](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Operadores_l%C3%B3gicos) `&&` en forma de [cortocircuito](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Operadores_l%C3%B3gicos#Evaluaci%C3%B3n_contra_corto_circuitos). Esto significa que si el objeto `query` no existe, todas las variables serán `undefined`, excepto por las dos últimas, que serán 0 y 20 respectivamente.

Luego, la evaluación de las condiciones se realizan sobre las variables `active` y `category`. Si las mismas son distintas de `undefined` (el operador `&&` evalúa si la condición es verdadera o falsa y devuelve el valor del primer argumento si el mismo evalúa a `false` o devuelve el valor del segundo argumento si el primero evalúa a `true`), entonces se añade la propiedad al objeto de filtro.

*¿Porqué evalúo `req.query`?*

La idea es establecer una ruta (*endpoint*) multipropósito, y como tal la solicitud puede contener o no valores de tipo [`Query String`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

Ejemplos de consultas:

```
GET /api/route/items //no tiene parámetros de consulta
GET /api/route/items?active=true // un sólo parámetro
GET /api/route/items?active=false&category=all // dos parámetros
GET /api/route/items?skip=5&limit=10 // dos parámetros para paginación
GET /api/route/items?dummy=true // este parámetro no es reconocido, se descarta
```

De esta forma no te tienes que preocupar cuántos o cuáles parámetros incluye tu consulta.

Es por esta razón que evaluamos la existencia o no del objeto `query`.

En Javascript los valores pueden ser [verdaderos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Truthy) o [falsos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Falsy) cuando se evalúan en un contexto booleano.

Si el objeto `req.query` no existe, su valor será `undefined` y al ser evaluado usando el operador `&&` será considerado `false`. Y como ya vimos, el operador `&&` devuelve el valor del primer operando cuando el mismo es evaluado a `false`.

Luego, las variables `category` y `active` pueden valer `undefined` o pueden tomar el valor de la clave almacenada en el objeto `query`.

Ejemplo de *cortocircuito* funcionando:

```js
const queries = [
  undefined,
  {},
  {active: true},
  {category: 'all'},
  {skip: 5},
  {limit: 10, skip: 30},
  {active: false, category: 'answers', skip: 10, limit: 15},
  {dummy: 'Soy dummy'}
];

queries.forEach(query => {
  const active = query && query.active;
  const category = query && query.category;
  const skip = (query && Number(query.skip)) || 0;
  const limit = (query && Number(query.limit)) || 20;
  const filter = {}
  if(category) {
    filter.category = category;
  }
  if(active) {
    filter.active = active;
  }
  console.log(filter);
  console.log(`skip: ${skip}, limit: ${limit}`);
  console.log('-------------------------------');
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Amigo, eres un crack!!!